# xslt for each condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following code -

xml -

```
<pctList    class="array">
<e  class="object">
<hotelID    type="number">10180</hotelID>
</e>
<e  class="object">
<hotelID    type="number">10181</hotelID>
</e>
<e  class="object">
<hotelID    type="number">10182</hotelID>
</e>
</pctList>
```

my xslt-

```
  <xsl:for-each select="pctList/e">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test='(hotelID = 10079)'>
                    <db:EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
                      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">SPECIAL RATE</xsl:text>
                    </db:EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <db:EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
                      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"></xsl:text>
                    </db:EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
```

the excepted output is only one -

```
<EIS_RATE_FIELD_2></EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
```

the  wrong output that I get when I use otherwise -

```
 <EIS_RATE_FIELD_2></EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
 <EIS_RATE_FIELD_2></EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
 <EIS_RATE_FIELD_2></EIS_RATE_FIELD_2>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your source xml - could you add a minimal example?

Comment: In addition to a minimal example of your XML input, also show a _complete_,minimal example of your XSLT stylesheet and the output you expect. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Based on your XSLT it is unclear why you are only expecting one output when you have 3 inputs. You are looking over each `e` element and outputting the `EIS_RATE_FIELD_2` for each one.

Comment: I know what the output should be. But my required output is as mentioned.

Comment: @Rotem87 Your example is not clear. Please explain the required logic in words.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `xsl:for-each`. Drop it but leave the `xsl:choose` and its contents. Then replace the line with `xsl:when` with this line:

```
<xsl:when test="pctList/e[hotelID = 10079]">
```

This will produce only one line: an empty `EIS_RATE_FIELD_2` element if there are no hotels with id 10079 *or* if there is, then the element will contain text "SPECIAL RATE".